# I am unable to exit From the while loop

Tags: python

```
# Dice Rolling Random Number and Guessing Game

import random

user_choice = 'y'


while user_choice != 'N' or user_choice != 'n':

    print(random.randint(1,6))
    user_choice = input("Do you want to continue: ")

print("You are exited")
```

Comment: You want to use `and`, not `or`. Or you can replace the condition with `while user_choice not in 'Nn':` or `while user_choice.lower() != 'n':`

Answer (score 2):

The logic of the while condition is wrong.

Your loop runs forever, because the character will ALWAYS be different from one of the suggested characters. So the while condition is always true as at least one of the two parts is always true.

You want something like

```
while user_choice != 'N' and user_choice != 'n':
    ...
```

If you want to go for a more 'pythonic' way, query a set in the while condition:

```
while user_choice not in {'n', 'N'}:
    ....
```

There are many similar ways with tuples, lists, ... to express the condition other than querying every character individually in a chain of 'and' conditions.

Comment: I would've used a tuple not a set, any advantage to a set or just personal preference?

Comment: It's one of many possibilities to formulate the condition differently - the first which sprung my mind when writing the answer. I added a sentence to make that clear.

Answer (score 0):

As far as coding is concerned, the question is answered already, but I'd like to offer a more deep explanation of why the answer was the `and` operation instead of `or`.

The question "*Did the user enter neither `'n'` or `'N'`?*" can be expressed using Boole Algebra as

- **Answer = Not(`'n'` or `'N'`)**, and using the DeMorgan theorem this can be rewritten as
- **Answer = Not(`'n'`) and Not(`'N'`)**

In your code, the first of the two ways to write this would look like

`while !(user_choice == 'N' or user_choice == 'n'):`

I hope this clears up the logic behind your question.